# Problems POSTing json to Node/Express server from Axios/React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I'm current working on a web application using Node.js with Express in the back-end and React.js in the front end. In attempting to post user data to the Node server, through axios, I am running into an issue. When I make a post with the x-www-form-urlencoded content type, the front end will post to the server but the entire JSON of the posted data appears in the key field of the first element. When I change the content type to json it stops posting anything from the front end. I have tried cUrling to the server, and curling a JSON post will get accepted by the server.

**React code to post to server**

```
handleSubmit()
  {
    var form=this;
    var axiosConfig = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      }
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login/', {
      'username': form.state.username,
      'password': form.state.password
    }, {headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}});

  };
```

**Server code for api endpoint**

```
//From server.js
const express=require('express');
const session=require('express-session');
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

var login = require('./routers/login')

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var app=express();

app.use(session({'secret': 'thealphabetbackwardsiszyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//...

app.use('/api/login', login);

//from login.js
/* Router for login system
   When user attempts to log in, check their credentials
   If the user successfully logs in, create a session
   If user enters invalid credentials prompt them
*/

const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const user = require("./../models/UserSchema")
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newt');

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res)
{
  console.log("Test");
})

router.post('/', function(req, res)
{
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end();
})

// To create test user use path localhost:8080/api/login/testing
router.get('/test', function (req, res)
{
  var db = mongoose.connection;

  var test = new user({
    username: "joesephschomseph",
    email: "testUser@test.com",
    fname: "Joe",
    lname: "Schmoe"
})

test.save();

console.log("Created test user!");
});


module.exports = router
```

Comment: try just  axios.post(URL,DATA) without the config, it should default post json

Comment: I have already tried removing the config, and I couldn't get anything to post at all

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install --save const body-parser
2. in app.js include const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
3. ```
   app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(bodyparser.json());
   ```
4. remove the single quotes from your 'username' and 'password'
5. console.log(req.body);

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed and included body-parser, I just forgot to include that code in my post. Removing the single quotes doesn't seem to make any difference as far as successfully getting the react app to post

Comment: Ok I see your issue now.  You are sending /api/login to this login function that is under require('./routers/login');  So that is where you want to write your console.log(req.body)  Also you need to make sure it has a post endpoint. Can you post the code located in that login.js file?

Comment: Just edited it to include the full code of login.js. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the endpoint because I can post to it just fine using `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"username": "test"}' http://localhost:8080/api/login/`

Comment: if you post with curl does the console.log work correctly?  Is the req.body populated?

Comment: Yep, if I post with curl the body is populated with the proper format ``{username: "test"}``, if I post from the client with the ``content-type:application/x-www-url-encoded`` it will post but the console.log call prints {"'username':'test'...": ""}, with the entirty of the JSON I send to the server being put into the key for the first value.

Comment: try this before you use it:

**const http = axios.create({
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  },
});**

then **http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login/', {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    });**

try this then see if the console.log works properly and also try it through postman.

Comment: Still no luck through the client. Postman is posting and the req.body is in the right format.

Comment: try using jquery and see if it works:

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data:  { username: 'username', password: 'password' },
  success: successCallBack,
  dataType: "json"
});

Comment: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>